# IF statement not working

Tags: javascript, html

sorry if i'm doing something monumentally stupid, but I can't get this IF statement working...

What it does is that it checks certain values from a cookie, setting combo box defaults.

Through debugging I can see that all the cookie variables are correct, however the IF statement does not seem to read the value? The first two IF's work correctly but the last else-if does not work.

Any help much appreciated, thanks

```
function checkBody() {
   var cookie1 = readCookie("Text Colour");
   textCol = cookie1 ? cookie1 : "#444";

   var cookie2 = readCookie("Background Colour");
   backCol = cookie2 ? cookie2 : "white";

   var cookie3 = readCookie("Link Colour");
   linkCol = cookie3 ? cookie3 : "#0424B5";

   var cookie4 = readCookie("Heading1 Colour");
   heading1Col = cookie4 ? cookie4 : "#0424B5";

   var cookie5 = readCookie("Headings Colour");
   headingsCol = cookie5 ? cookie5 : "#99975A";

   var element = document.getElementById('colours');
   if(textCol == cookie1 && backCol == cookie2)
      element.value = "#444,white,#0424B5,#0424B5,#99975A";
   else if(textCol == cookie1 && backCol == cookie2)
      element.value = "black,yellow,black,black,black";
   else if(textCol == cookie1 && backCol == cookie2)
      element.value = "black,#87CEFA,black,black,black";

   bodyStyle(textCol,backCol,linkCol,heading1Col,headingsCol);
}
```

Comment: All 3 of your if statements use the exact same comparison... (`textCol == cookie1 && backCol == cookie2`)

Comment: i'm an idiot i just could not see that, thanks very much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All the `if` are same. the latter two are never reached.

```
...
else if(textCol == cookie1 && backCol == cookie2)
    element.value = "black,yellow,black,black,black";
else if(textCol == cookie1 && backCol == cookie2)
    element.value = "black,#87CEFA,black,black,black";
...
```